# "PXE-E61: media test failure" while trying to install Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, installation, boot, windows-server-2008

I was trying to install Windows Server 2008 R2 on my new Dell XPS Laptop. A "PXE-E61: media test failure" error was showing while trying to install from DVD Drive of the laptop. I tried to troubleshoot it using the following steps, but didn't succeed.

1. Made HDD the first option in the boot order priority.
2. Disabled Inbuilt NIC. Didn't find any option to disable PXE boot.
3. With the same DVD I was able to install Win2008 on a desktop machine. In the desktop machine, the Wind2008R2 installation prompts with a menu with number 1. and 2. nothing next to it, usually I select option "1" and hit enter key.
4. To make sure there's no problem with the laptop HDD and DVD drive. I tried installing the Windows 7 Home premium on the laptop using the accompanied disk that came along with the laptop. The installation went successfully without any issues.

I am not sure why this issue only shows up in my laptop and not on my desktop machine. Please help me to sort this out.

Comment: Try using F12 to select the dvd drive as the boot device.

Answer (score 0):

At last I was able to sort this out in a roundabout way. My laptop was already installed with Windows 7 and I was trying to make it dual boot by installing Win2008 R2 on a different partition. So as a last resort I tried to initialize the Win2008 R2 installation by logging on to Win7 and accessing the setup from the DVD drive. to my fate an error popped up which reads "unsupported format" something like that.

To resolve this I installed MagicISO loaded the iso image for Win2008 R2, extracted the files to a partition on my  laptop and started the installation from there. Everything went perfectly fine.

The issue which I had posted comes up only when trying to boot up from the DVD.